# How to remove similar elements from a Dart list?

Tags: list, dart, element, equivalent

I'd like to remove similar elements from a dart list, where similarity is given by some boolean function.
For example in Mathematica I would achieve that as follows:

```mathematica
Union[{2, -2, 1, 3, 1}, SameTest -> (Abs[#1] == Abs[#2] &)]
```

This statement yields the following list - {-2, 1, 3}. Effectively I'd like to keep one element from each equivalence class.

I know there is a function list.retainWhere( (e) => bool test(e) ), unfortunately this test can only operate on one value at a time. Another option, of course, I could do something like this (just writing from my head)

```dart
i=0;
for(final E in list) {
  i++;      
  for(j=i; j<list.skip(i).length; j++) {
     if sameTest(e, E) then list.removeAt(i+j);
  }  
}
```

but i find this bit ugly.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**
I will clarify my problem in more details and then show how to solve it using advice given below.

```dart
  class Pair<T> {
    final T left;
    final T right;
    Pair(this.left, this.right);    
  }
```

Now I want to have a structure holding such pair or *points*, and i don't want to hold point which are sufficiently close to each other. To do so I adopt solution of Alexandre Ardhuin and his comment too, which actually makes a difference for more complicated cases: *Considering 2 elements `e1` and `e2` you have to define `hashCode` to ensure that `e1.hashCode == e2.hashCode` if `e1 == e2`*

so here it goes:

```dart
int N=1000;

LinkedHashSet<Pair<double>> myset =
    new LinkedHashSet<Pair<double>>(
      equals: (Pair<double> e1, Pair<double> e2) =>            
        (e1.left - e2.left)*(e1.left - e2.left) + (e1.right - e2.right)*(e1.right - e2.right) < 1/N,
      hashCode: (Pair<double> e){
        int ex = (e.left*N).round();
        int ey = (e.right*N).round();
        return (ex+ey).hashCode;
      }
);

List<Pair<double>> list = [new Pair<double>(0.1,0.2), new Pair<double>(0.1,0.2001)];
myset.addAll( list );
```

the result will be `{0.1,0.2}`. If the second element of `list` is altered to `{0.1, 0.201}` I predictably get a set with two elements.

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [LinkedHashSet](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-collection.LinkedHashSet) and define the *equals* and *hashcode* to use.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

main() {
  final result = new LinkedHashSet<int>(
      equals: (int e1, int e2) => e1.abs() == e2.abs(),
      hashCode: (int e) => e.abs().hashCode);
  result.addAll([2, -2, 1, 3, 1]);
  print(result); // {2, 1, 3}
}
```

Comment: looks good, but I still have difficulties with, I guess, hash codes.  I have a class `class Pair<T> { final T left; final T right;}` then I try to declare a hashset  
`new LinkedHashSet<Pair<double>>(equals: (Pair<double> e1, Pair<double> e2) => (e1.left-e2.left)^2 + (e1.right-e2.right)^2< 0.01, hashCode: (Pair<double> e) => e.hashCode );`
I.e. only sufficiently distant pairs must stay. Let `list = [new Pair<double>(0.1,0.2), new Pair<double>(0.1,0.200001)]` the distance between the two is less that 0.01. But `myset.addAll( list )` contains two elements instead of one. How do i solve it?

Comment: Considering 2 elements _e1_ and _e2_ you have to define _hashCode_ to ensure that `e1.hashCode == e2.hashCode` if `e1 == e2`. This is not the case for your code. If you don't really care about performances you can always use `hashCode: (e) => 0` that satisfies the condition I mentioned above.